# RollingFile Appender Log4j2 not printing Line number

Tags: logging, log4j2, line-numbers, rollingfileappender, pattern-layout

I am using log4j2 with following dependency ::

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using following configuration ::

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOGGER_HOME">/logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="application" fileName="${LOGGER_HOME}/application.log"
            filePattern="${LOGGER_HOME}/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log">

            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601}{GMT} %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
            </Policies>

        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="framework" fileName="${LOGGER_HOME}/em-logs/framework.log"
            filePattern="${LOGGER_HOME}/framework.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log">

            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601}{GMT} %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="out" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601}{GMT} %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <Async name="asyncApplication">
            <AppenderRef ref="application" />
        </Async>

        <Async name="asyncFramework">
            <AppenderRef ref="framework" />
        </Async>


    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.memorynotfound.logging" level="debug"
            includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="asyncApplication" />
        </Logger>

    <Root level="debug" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="asyncApplication"></AppenderRef>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="org.axonframework" level="info" additivity="false"
            includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="asyncFramework" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="error" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="out" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>


</Configuration>
```

However i am getting logs on the console in the following format

```
2015-08-20 14:29:41,613 DEBUG logging.LoggerExample (LoggerExample.java:11) - This will be printed on debug
```

And in the Rolling file i get following pattern where the line number is missing ::

```
2015-08-20 14:29:41,613 DEBUG ? () - This will be printed on debug
```

I have gone nuts as nothing seem to work for printing the line numbers i also followed the official log4j2 link 
[Log4j2 Migration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) 
but still the result is same as above. If any one has any solution please let me know .

Comment: use %L in your pattern, it will append line number to you log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i found the solution ::
[Log4j2 AsyncLogger with rolling file appender not showing file line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820765/log4j2-asynclogger-with-rolling-file-appender-not-showing-file-line-number)

Then i changed my appender reference to directly point to RollingFile name instead of `<Async name>` , it is now correctly showing the line number . Not sure why this happens, I will find and soon post the reason.

So changed the following ::

```
<Logger name="com.memorynotfound.logging" level="debug"
            includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="asyncApplication" />
        </Logger>
```

to

```
<Logger name="com.memorynotfound.logging" level="debug"
        includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="application" />
    </Logger>
```

Answer (score 3):

For the consideration of performance, async logger closed the includeLocation by default. If you want to print the line num and class name, you need add `<Async name="asyncFramework" includeLocation="true">`

FYI
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation

Answer (score 3):

The document describe the reason that not printing line number .
It say you can override the default behaviour in your logger or asynchronous appender configuration by specifying `includeLocation="true"`.
But i did not solve the problem that not printing line number after i did it.
Maybe because i didn`t understand what it meant, i made the wrong place.

My solution is add `%L` in Log4j2 PatternLayout pattern.
My Log4j2.xml is following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="LOG_HOME">./logs</Property>
        </Properties>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFileInfo" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/pinche_quartz.log"
                     filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/test.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFileError" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/error/pinche_quartz-error.log"
                     filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/error/pinche_quartz-error.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <root level="all">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileInfo"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileError"/>
        </root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I hope to help you.

Log4j2 document https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation